# f (x) = f (f (x))

Tags: mathematics

> A function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfies $f(x) = f(f(x))$ if and only if:
>
> - $f(x) = x$, or
> - $f(x) = c$ (where $c$ is a constant).

*"Huh? Yes, yes, it is of course true,"* is what I think right now.
But a friend of mine told me that the statement... is false. There is (*or are*) another function $f$ that satisfies $f(x) = f(f(x))$.

Find that (*or those*) function $f$.

Comment: Does the expected answer deal with infinity, where anything is possible?

Comment: @Phylyp, no. The answer doesn't deal with infinity-thing, :)

Comment: I reckon mod 2, so for example 7 mod 2 = 1, and then, 1 mod 2  = 1 again, but before i realised that, the answer looked legit!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function with this property is called [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). Examples of idempotent functions include:

- $x\mapsto |x|$
- $x \mapsto \max(x,5)$
- $x\mapsto \lfloor x \rfloor$

and many, *many* more.

Comment: Wah, I don't realize that there is a function property like that. Thanks for such info! ^^ --- Well, my answer is actually $f(0) = 42$ and $f(x) = x$ when $x \neq 0$, but yaaa~

Answer (score 2):

One possible such function might be

> $f(x) = \lfloor \frac12x \rfloor\times 2$

where $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ would indeed be the case, but where $f(1) \ne f(2)$

Comment: f(1) = 4, but f(f(1)) = 16. I'm not sure this works.

Comment: @abligh whoops, messed up in mathjax conversion - fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.